# Integrating Meetup.com API with Mobile App

Tags: rest, meetup

I wanted to get all the events from the Meetup.com whichever I have enrolled.

I am not quite understanding :urlname.

Can you please suggest me the API / REST Call.

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in the Meetup.com [api console](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/2/events)  - the endpoint is GET /2/events.
You will want to enter the parameters:

```
rsvp=yes,
member_id=self,
status=past,
page=200,
desc=false,
omit=description
```

Then click on **Show Response**.  You can either read the response there or I find it easier to **copy the signed link** and paste it into a browser window and hit return.  Then select all the JSON text that comes back and paste it into the left pane in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and tap the little arrow to get it mapped into fields in the right hand pane

Comment: Thanks, Can you please suggest me the api paramaters for the below meetup event ? https://www.meetup.com/AmericanAngels/